# How to select and store string values in pandas using regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I want to select and store string values(regex) into variable. Here I want to extract USD, 1000.00, 21/01/2022 from Name and store into separate variables for amount = 1000.0, date = 21/01/2022 and currency = USD respectively.

```py
import pandas as pd

data_dict = {
            'Name': ['I paid USD 1000.00 on 21/01/2022 for car service']
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

Comment: are they always in the same order? Is the currency always before the number? Can there be more numbers? currencies? list of wanted currencies? Please give more details and a few more lines of example

Comment: Hi mozway, there could be different currency like USD or EUR and for amount it can be anything like 10,000 or 200.00. The order of flow remains same currency first, amount second and date at last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order is consistent and the currency always right before the amount, a simple regex with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) should work:

```
df['Name'].str.extract(r'(?P<currency>[A-Z]{3})\s*(?P<amount>\d+(?:\.\d+)).*(?P<date>\d\d/\d\d/\d{4})')
```

output:

```
  currency   amount        date
0      USD  1000.00  21/01/2022
```

###### *Notes*

- This won't validate the date (99/00/9876 would match)
- This assumes the currency is 3 uppercase letters (you can easily adapt)
- The type of all columns is string, if you plan to use the amount or date for operations you must convert them

##### variant: numbers with decimal separator

```
out = df['Name'].str.extract(r'(?P<currency>[A-Z]{3})\s*(?P<amount>\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)).*(?P<date>\d\d/\d\d/\d{4})')
```

example:

```
  currency      amount        date
0      USD     1000.00  21/01/2022
1      USD  100,000.00  21/01/2022
```

Comment: I added another variant in case of numbers like `'100,000.00'`